# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error and I have no idea why but it's not happy with the following line:

```
<p className="bold blue padding-left-30">{question}</p>
```

It's not liking the `{question}` portion of the above paragraph.

from:

```
const Questions = Component({
    render(){
        var questions = this.props.questions;
        questions = questions ? questions.map(
            (question) =>
                <div className="all-100 align-left">
                    <p className="bold blue padding-left-30">{question}</p>
                    <blockquote className="margin-left-50 medium fw-300">{question.answer ? question.answer : ""}</blockquote>
                </div>
        ): "";

        return(<div>{questions}</div>);
    }
});
```

Here's what the questions array portion looks like from json:

```
"questions": [
        {
          "question": "This is Question 1",
          "answer": [
            "blah blah blah 1"
          ]
        },
        {
          "question": "This is Question 2",
          "answer": [
            "blah blah blah 2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "question": "This is Question 3",
          "answer": [
            "blah blah blah 3"
          ]
        }
      ]
```

The answer prints out fine but that's done by another react component called `<Answer />`.

So what does that mean? invariant violation in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that point question is an object, since you're mapping over it, and you're trying to use it inside of JSX, which isn't allowed. Did you mean to do

```
<p className="bold blue padding-left-30">{question.question}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the full question object in the p tag

```
<p className="bold blue padding-left-30">{question.question}</p>
```